# Geoserver over HTTPS

Tags: iis, https

I posted this question on gis.stackexchange (gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383728/geoserver-over-https) but they closed it considering off-topic... (it seems that geoserver and WMS are not gis questions...)

Anyway, I installed GeoServer 2.18.1 on a windows 2008 server with IIS7. On layer preview I can see my layers on OpenLayers, so everything is ok. The URL of the preview is (http)mysite.com:8080/geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS (etc).

I need to use GeoServer over HTTPS on a PHP website, so I did:

- installed HTTPS certificate on IIS
- on geoserver, under global settings, added "(https)mysite.com:8080/geoserver" to Proxy Base URL

But now, when I preview the same layer I see a blank map. Using inspector I found an error on the request URL: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

So, GeoServer WMS works ok over HTTP but not over HTTPS.

I found some related posts but they use other configuration like tomcat/apache/other, mine uses windows server/IIS/JRE/geoserver.

Any idea? Did I miss any configuration?

Comment: Your question was closed because GeoServer and WMS don't care about how you set up SSL on IIS.

Comment: Try to set Proxy Base URL in global settings, [https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html).

Comment: @samwu: i already did that

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, from my recent experience deploying a `GeoServer`.

`Geoserver` runs on port:8080 (not secure) so the request has to be proxied on this port

You have to set up a reverse proxy server using IIS

I can not help you further, I have done recently this by using apache.